# Terminal "f" versus "ff" in anglicized Russian surnames

Tags: orthography, surnames, transliteration, russian, anglicization

Today, foreign names are anglicized more or less systematically from their original spelling: the Russian surname "Петров" generally becomes "Petrov", not the calqued "Peterson" or the more phonetic "Petrof" or "Petroff" (which  reflect [final-obstruent devoicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing)). The phonetic type of surname anglicization was apparently in style at least as recently as the early 1900s, when Rachmaninoff (Рахманинов) started coming to the United States.

Insofar as writers sought to anglicize -в surnames by their sound, what norms and influences guided the choice between -ff and -f? Was -ff influenced by German or French orthography?  Does -f "look wrong" to some readers? Is the -ff supposedly a longer sound, and if so, why would one be called for? Was either spelling ever more canonical?

Comment: Except for *of*, the only English words ending with *of* end with *oof* (like *proof, roof, hoof*) and have a different vowel than *Rachmaninoff* and *Pavlov*. So maybe the double f was chosen by analogy with English words like *off* and *doff*.

Comment: Great point @PeterShor. in that light, the -of ("Baranof") seems like the outlier.

Comment: A relevant Russian SE question: [Sergei Rachmaninov or Rachmaninoff](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/4460)

Comment: Cyrillic names don't get English-spelled very consistently. Occasionally we borrow foreign spellings from the wrong language, like _Tschaikovsky_, which is German spelling, not Russian.